# JavaScript - Collapse Div

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to collapse my `div` where I can still see it. However, its contents have been collapsed and when you hover over it, it displays at normal size and its contents are visible.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this, but I have started just trying to change the div's size directly by id or class and haven't managed to accomplish anything yet.

I have some sister divs beneath it that serve as a sub menu. I can change their size in CSS with the same #divID however, it's not changing my first one. I just need the first one collapsed. It's basically a menu that i used the input CSS hack for displaying divs

The styles div is the one I would like to collapse.
My code thus far:

```js
var collapse = document.getElementById("styles");
collapse.setAttribute("style", "height:5px");
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="UItab" id="tabf">
<label for="tabf"><a href="index.php?page=styles"><span>Styles</span></a>
</label>
<div>
  <div id="styles">
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <a href="index.php?page=sAdminNew">
        <li>New Style</li>
      </a>
      <a href="index.php?page=sAdminExist" onclick="toggle('togglebox');">
        <li>Existing Styles</li>
      </a>
      <a href="index.php?page=sAdminAssign">
        <li>Style Assignments</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

 input + label {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 6px 8px 10px 24px;
 height: 8px;
 margin:0;
 line-height: 12px;
 position:relative;
}

input + label + div{
 margin:0;
 margin-top:2px;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 1px solid;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 display: none;
 
}
 
input:checked + label + div { 
 display:block; 
 
 }
/*CSS for submenu container  */
 .menu input + label + div {
 position: absolute;
 right:0;
 background-image: url('../images/submenu-background.png');
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto; 
}
 
.menu input + label + div > div {
 z-index:1000;
 position:absolute; 
 top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; 
 padding:16px;
 padding-top:5px;
 
}
```

Comment: `<a>` is not valid content directly in [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). And what you think `a` will do after clicking?

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is change visibility, you'd have a much more reliable solution by using CSS rather than JS, since Javascript can be unavailable for a whole host of reasons.

```
#styles{
    height:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#styles:hover{
    height:auto;
}
```

And with those simple style declarations you will see it expand/collapse. If you're looking for animation, though, its a much more complex solution.

If in the collapsed state you want it to only show the first line of text (so you can have like a "label" or something), it might be smarter to use "ems" instead of "px":

```
#styles{
    height:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here, 1em = the height of one line's worth of text.

Comment: It might be important to add `display: block;` as well.

Comment: I have some sister divs beneath it that serve as a sub menu. I can  change their size in CSS with the same #divID however, it's not changing my first one. I just need the first one collapsed. It's basically a menu that i used the input CSS hack for displaying divs. I'll post my CSS.